# ConTeXt: Cannot typeset four consecutive hyphens

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I'm having trouble typsetting four consecutive hyphens in a custom font.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\definesimplefont[myfonthere][myfontname]

\starttext
{\myfonthere ----}
\stoptext
```

This always comes out as two italicized hyphens.  I need four separate hyphens, because this is to represent rolling four minuses on a set of Fudge Dice, which are dice that let you roll a value between -4 and +4.

This may be an incredibly newbie question, but I'm new to ConTeXt, and none of my LaTeX tricks are working here.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so instead of editing your answer into the question it should be an own answer – _and you have in fact written a separate answer._ Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I saw the "answer your question" button after editing the answer in... and must have forgotten to edit it out!

Answer (score 5):

My answer is based on [Wolfgang's answer](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/76565). When the font feature `tlig` is active, TeX ligatures are active — including the one that merges `--` into '–'. You can turn off all font features in the *proper* way, as described by Wolfgang, if you want such things several times in your document. If you want those discrete dashes just once or twice, this might be good enough for you:

```
----                           % dashes get merged
{\setfontfeature{none} ----}   % dashes don't get merged
----                           % dashes get merged
```

If you want to save typing, `\setff` is a shorter synonym for `\setfontfeature`.

Comment: Where can I find a description of the exact function of `\setff`?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: A combination of two documents, and some guesswork. 1: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setff 2:http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf, section 5.10 **Font feature sets**, `tlig` defaults to `no`, so not mentioning it in my `\setff` should work.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: Looking back at the thread in question, Wolfgang specifies that `\setff` is just an alias for`\setfontfeature`. Given that, the description in contextref.pdf applies directly.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: See [Fonts out of MkIV](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf) for details about font features.

Comment: `\addfontfeature`, `\setfontfeature` etc. are nearing obsolescence. Please consult [this announcement by Hans](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2013/071903.html) for a demonstration of the new, soon to be canonical interface.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to comments to prash's answer, I hacked together this solution:

```
\definesimplefont[myfonthere][myfontname][features=none]

\starttext
{\myfonthere ----}
\stoptext
```

That `features=none` turned out to be the key.